# Single word for "to start earlier"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that indicates that a time interval (or event) will start earlier than previously expected. It should contrast with "to prolong", because that's also something that can happen to the same interval (and "prolongation" is already used in that context).

Summary:

```
"last longer"   -> "prolongation"
"start earlier" -> ???
```

Context:

We are sending severe weather warnings to customers, mostly a few hours in advance. Sometimes it happens that the severe weather lasts longer than expected, we call that a "prolongation" internally. In this case we may send "prolongation warnings".

Similarly, it can happen that the severe weather starts earlier than expected. The duration may or may not be affected by this (the event can be longer than we anticipated, have the same duration and just start earlier, or it may even be shorter). I've started calling this an "earlification", which transports the meaning, but is a little lacking in elegance.

Just to clarify, these words are used in internal, informal documentation and source code. They are not used in communication with customers.

Comment: Better include an example sentence to understand the usage and context better.

Comment: *Advancing* is what I'd use. "The program was advanced by an hour." (i.e., Commenced/ was to commence an hour earlier than scheduled.)

Comment: Yeah, at first I got completely the wrong impression. If something is prolonged, then it takes more time. Yet, if something starts early, that doesn't mean it will be shortened.

Comment: @Kris: I've updated the question with some context how the word will be used.

Comment: Accelerated is the word I would use. In context; "The storm was on an accelerated path". However, I think with any word you chose for an early situation a qualifier would need to made that it only early. Most synonyms would imply a shorter duration as well. However, if the word is only to used internally, anything that you and your team can agree on would be acceptable.

Comment: I’d automatically think that [*earlification*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earl) must be a bloviated equivalent to *counting*.

Comment: @Kris Certainly [advanced](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/postpone?s=t) is the [top choice](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/defer) for something that’s been “moved up” rather than “put off” in time. Or just plain *be early*.

Comment: Why not just say it got a "head start."

Comment: Google "synonym early".

Comment: In British English, the colloquialism "previous" is often used when something starts earlier than expected as in "That was a bit previous".

Comment: I was going to suggest "accelerated" although I don't think "accelerated path" would be clear to me from that sentence above: *timelines* are accelerated though. I think "acceleration" might work as a noun.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about naming are off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For severe weather starting earlier: **hastening**.

> to cause (something) to happen more quickly - [MW](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hasten)

Comment: @Skooba And by [equally valid definition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hasten) it means "cause something to occur sooner"

Comment: "Hastening" can most certainly be used in this context, "The commuters were caught off-guard by the *hastening* onset of the storm."

Answer (score 2):

When something occurs earlier than expected, it is [***premature***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/premature).

Answer (score 1):

Consider, ***early/earliness*** [Oxford French-English Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/french-english/precoce)

> early: occurring, developing, or appearing before the expected or usual time
>
> earliness: quality of coming early or earlier in time [Wordnet by Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/earliness)
>
> *The [earliness](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Pdqhrt-Q4NkC&pg=PA168&lpg=PA168&dq=%22earliness+of+the+storm%22&source=bl&ots=rsymVYOvDc&sig=KD9QCs11Xw9XnQRSE7AvzD9H0g4&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCooPJxdHJAhWMmBoKHSd3AmoQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22earliness%20of%20the%20storm%22&f=false) of the storm caught cars without snow tires or chains*

Answer (score 1):

You may consider **prematurely**

> : happening too soon or earlier than usual
>   :  happening, arriving, existing, or performed before the proper, usual, or intended time; especially

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/premature)

I also like the word **over-early** because it is fun to say, but I don't think people use it much outside of prose

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of *postpone*, is *prepone*

> Bring (something) forward to an earlier date or time - [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/prepone)

Comment: Be aware that this is not a word used by almost any native speakers anywhere. It is dialectal slang.

Comment: In fact the ODO entry referenced specifically mentions *Indian,* and it would be worthwhile mentioning that limited regional use in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'antecipate' (antecipation) and 'precipitate' (precipitation) are good words for that.

**EDIT**

You can see their definitions here: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anticipation and here: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/precipitation

Comment: Actually it's "anticipate / anticipation"....  Also, can you add some examples, definitions, or other support for your answer?